# RNA-Seq: Is it conventional to use a threshold RPKM value to determine if a gene of interest is expressed in a sample?

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-sequencing, biostatistics

I am interested in finding out at what stages of development a gene of interest is expressed in the human brain. I am using the [Developmental Transcriptome](https://www.brainspan.org/rnaseq/searches?exact_match=false&search_term=%22NECTIN-3%22&search_type=gene) tool from the Allen Brain Atlas to find this information. The heatmap showing the gene expression levels across the different brain samples (taken from donors of different ages) was generated from RNA-Seq data.

[image]

[image]

From the official documentation on how the RNA-Seq data for the Developmental Transcriptome was normalised, RPKM (Reads Per Kilobase Million) were the gene expression units that were used in the RNA-Seq data analysis. The gene expression values were then transformed into a log scale (log2 RPKM) for easier visualisation on the heatmap.

From visually looking at the heatmap, you can see at which stages of development the gene of interest is expressed, with brighter colours (light blue, green) indicating a higher level of expression compared to dark blue regions of the heatmap. However, I do not think that visually looking at the heatmap colours is an unbiased way to determine at which stages of development a certain gene is expressed.

I am completely new to analysing RNA-Seq data. This might be a basic question, but is it a convention/practice in research to use a "threshold/cutoff" RPKM value to determine whether a gene of interest is expressed in a sample? E.g. If a sample has a log2RPKM above the threshold value then you consider that gene to be expressed at a sufficient level.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Please specify what"sufficient level" means. You are trying to convert something that is continuous into a binary — IMO this makes unsupported assumptions. 2) This also assumes the level is a constant! 3) Is your gene of interest protein coding? If so, to really know whether the expression meant something you would need to do something like show it was also translated and then confirm that the protein meant something — e.g. by observing an effect after preventing the protein from acting at that stage. ——— Bioinformatics is great, but it is not a substitute for wet experiments ...

Comment: The proportion of reads containing the mRNA of your gene is all what RNA-seq can tell. What else do you expect from it? The relevant cutoff probably depends on the function of the protein, and the exact methodology of the RNA-seq experiment.

Comment: possibly a better fit for bioinformtics.stackexchange.com. I think that the real question here is about what the "limit of detection" (LOD) is for bulk RNA-seq of some depth. One example of an assay doing something similar is here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29929942/. There are some statistical procedures used to estimate this LOD, which would ideally include a spike-in control of standards of some kind. RPKM is hard because it is an inherently relative/compositional measure; LOD RPKM will vary from expt to expt based on e.g. depth.

Comment: I checked and your resource's documentation does contain information about data processing and spike-in controls, I'd suggest consulting that: https://help.brain-map.org/download/attachments/3506181/Transcriptome_Profiling.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1382036562736&api=v2